# How to setup HP printer in CUPS?

Tags: cups, hplip

`hplip` and `hplip-cups` are installed. The model is LaserJet P4515, but is not listed when I want to setup the printer. How do I setup a HP printer?

Comment: You can install according this:
[http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/install/index.html](http://web.archive.org/web/20131102153126/http://hplipopensource.com/hplip-web/install/install/index.html)

Answer (score 6):

Login as root then open a terminal and type `hp-setup` after that just follow the process.

Comment: installing the `hplip` package in my distro and then invoking `hp-setup` from a terminal worked for me, and no need to be root : it can be setup for a single user

Answer (score 1):

In ubuntu 12.04, with hplip and cups installed, I found I could add the printer directly from the Printing console, by going to Find a Network Printer, and then selecting the printer, and then accepting the default connection of a "Remote CUPS printer via DNS-SD (...)"

Answer (score 1):

Wanting to use my new HP Color LaserJet Pro M252dw in Mint 17.3 KDE (which does not by default have a ppd for it) as well as in Mint 18.1 KDE (which does have such a ppd), have found a way to copy over the necessary file.

1. Searching Mint 18.1 for *.ppd revealed that they are stocked mostly in /usr/share/ppd/hplip/HP and the ones that are installed and useable are in /usr/share/ppd/cupsfilters with owner root and permissions 0644.

2  The actual installation proved surprisingly simple: I copied the appropriate .ppd file to Mint 17.3's /usr/share/ppd/cupsfilters, set its owner and permissions as mentioned in step 1, and installed the printer with the Printers gui in System Settings.

It printed a test page successfully on first attempt.